# In LibreOffice Calc, how can I change the cell selection black ring to something lighter for dark backgrounds?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice-calc, cells, contrast

In LibreOffice Calc, how can I change the cell selection black ring to something lighter so it can be easier to see for dark backgrounds? I will attach an image to show what I mean. It would be nice if it could auto-detect if a background is dark and make it white instead of black. Is there an option somewhere to change this manually? This may also apply to OpenOffice Calc if there is a solution since they are so similar.

Example:

[image: Can't see black ring cell selection]

In this example, the "TOTAL SALES" cell is selected but the black ring is very hard to see.

Comment: Like a "negative" colour option for the highlight box... sounds like a good feature request